# why does floatformat:2 adds a comma after the hundred place

Tags: python, django, django-tagging

I have a Django project and I have a {{account.current_balance}} tag in my HTML. I also included the type of data it is just in case it matters. I understand #1 and #2, but I don't understand why with #3, adding intcomma would add a comma after the hundred place.

1. **Tag without floatformat or intcomma**

   {{ account.current_balance }}

output:
Current Balance - Type
303.6000000000000 - Decimal

2. **Tag with floatformat:2**

   {{ account.current_balance|floatformat:2 }}

output:
Current Balance - Type
303.60 - Decimal

3. **Tag with floatformat:2 with intcomma**

   {{ account.current_balance|floatformat:2|intcomma }}

output:
Current Balance - Type
,303.60 - Decimal

adding models.py and views.py

```
class BankAccount(models.Model):
    beginning_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    transaction_date = models.DateField()
```

```
class UserHome(LoginRequiredMixin, AccountContextMixin, ListView):
    model = Transaction
    template_name = 'base_app/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'transactions'
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return self.model.objects.filter(user=user).filter(status="Posted").order_by('-transaction_date')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        
        total_balance = 0
        
        home_get_accounts = BankAccount.objects.filter(in_report='Yes')
        for account in home_get_accounts:
            posted_transactions_sum = Transaction.objects.filter(bank_account=account, status='Posted').aggregate(total=models.Sum('amount'))['total'] or 0
            current_balance = posted_transactions_sum + account.beginning_balance
            account.current_balance = current_balance  # Adding current_balance attribute to account instance

            total_balance += current_balance
            
            print(type(total_balance))
    
        context['home_get_accounts'] = home_get_accounts #for Beginning Balances
        context['total_balance'] = total_balance
        context['total_balance_type'] = type(total_balance).__name__
        return context
```

Comment: Share the related view and model(s).

Comment: Did try other order {{ account.current_balance|intcomma|floatformat:2 }}

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I updated my post and added view and model. ty

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby yes. the comma disappears, but anything that is over 1000 is not rendered or disappears.

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat 5.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Django having [issue #35172](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/35172). It has been solved for the LTS releases in versions 3.2.25+ and 4.2.11+, for the current major version it has been solved in version 5.0.3 onwards.

The solution to fix this would be to upgrade to a version of Django where this is fixed.

Comment: I upgraded and it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

when using the intcomma filter along with floatformat filter in Django templates. The intcomma filter is used to add commas to large numbers for better readability, but it seems to be affecting the decimal portion of your number as well.

> Tag without floatformat or intcomma

```
{{ account.current_balance }}
```

This simply outputs the current balance without any formatting applied.

> Tag with floatformat

```
{{ account.current_balance|floatformat:2 }}
```

This applies the floatformat filter to round the number to 2 decimal places.

> Tag with floatformat:2 with intcomma:

```
{{ account.current_balance|floatformat:2|intcomma }}
```

This applies both floatformat and intcomma filters. The floatformat filter rounds the number to 2 decimal places, and then the intcomma filter adds commas to the integer part of the number.